# cannot find for sibling folders and files from path mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I have some bunch of paths i want to get result only for sibling folders and files of a given folders. example i have paths like following

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\index2.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\index2.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\php\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\php\index2.php
```

if search with wp-content i want results `wp-content` root files and folders alone (wp-content root files and its sibling folder `dark` alone)

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\index2.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\index2.php
```

if search with dark. i want results `dark` root files and folders alone like following

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\index2.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\php\index1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\dark\php\index2.php


SELECT * FROM table WHERE  file REGEXP 'wp-content[*\\{2,3}]'
```

i tried like above this does not works. 
i want matches like after `wp-content`(searching folder) only `1 or 2 not more than that` slashes should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters inside `[]` is a character set, an means that the next character must match one of them (or whatever number a quantifier specifies). **Your** regex checks for the text `wp-content` followed one of the characters `*`, `\`, `{`, `2`, `,`, `3` or `}`.

What you want is perhaps something like

```
wp-content\\[^\\]+(\\[^\\]+)?$
```

which wold check for your string `wp-content`, followed by a `\` which in turn is followed by characters **not** being a `\` (the `^` in the character class negates it).

Then **optionally** it can be followed by another `\` followed by characters again  **not** being a `\`.

Finally it must match the end of the text - `$`.

[See it at regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/jK2qH5/1).

Regards

Comment: thank for the answer but it returns nothing in phpmyadmin.

Comment: tried this also `wp-content\\\\[^\\\\]+(\\\\[^\\\\]+)?$`

Comment: It works for me. Check [the example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/nj3c-w20j). I created a table with your "files". Run the example to see it work. (Changed `\ ` to `/` for simplicity.)

Comment: yes it works for `/` slash.  for this `\ ` it brings all the rows as `file REGEXP 'wp-content\[^\]+(\[^\]+)?$'`

Comment: also if you search with `htdocs` it does not work. which folder has at-least one files in root then only it works

Comment: This is beyond my understanding of php and mysql. I used trial and error and found that I had to *double escape* `\ ` to get it into the DB, and *quadruple escape* in the regex??? [Check it here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/izbt-v1fa). This works but I can't explain it...Sorry.

Comment: hey and if i search like `htdocs` it does not returns. `wp1` folder. it is actually a sibling folder. i think problem lies in regex.